# Creating word table with merged cells in R flextable

Tags: r, flextable

I have to create a table in R that exports to word and should look something like this:
[image: ex table].

As you can see there are several merged and non-merged cells in this table. Side note I will have to do this for 100's of patients eventually.

I am using flextable and markdown and got reasonably close to this table by merging cells using the `merge_at()` function. My question is, is there a more elegant way to accomplish this table than my solution? I am open to other packages but needs to stay in R. My code is minimal and I will clean up the labels later so that is not the issue here.

My code:

```
library(flextable)
library(dplyr)



sampledata <- data.frame(Name = c("Jane Doe"),CCSSID = c("1"),
                         "DOB"= c(as.Date(10000,origin = "1970-01-01")),
                         AgeofDX = c(10), cancerDX = c("Hodgkin Lymphoma"),
                         dxdate = c(as.Date(13000,origin = "1970-01-01")),
                         center = c("Hosp")
                         
                         ,stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

jane <- filter(sampledata, CCSSID == 1)
#make all character for binding 
jane[] <- sapply(jane, as.character)

jane1 <- jane |> select(1:2) 
colnames(jane1) <- c("var1","var2")
jane2 <- jane |> select(3:4)
colnames(jane2) <- c("var1","var2")
jane3 <- jane |> select(5)
colnames(jane3) <- c("var1")
jane4 <- jane |> select(6)
colnames(jane4) <- c("var1")
jane5 <- jane |> select(7)
colnames(jane5) <- c("var1")


janec <- do.call(bind_rows, list(jane1,jane2,jane3,jane4,jane5
                 ))



flextable(janec)   |>
  merge_at(3,1:2)   |>
  merge_at(4,1:2)   |>
  merge_at(5,1:2)
```

[image: flextable]